# uneditable entry box(widget) in tkinter after using in if-condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter form to update a student's record in mysql table with respect to USN. I'm trying to first check whether the USN entered by the user is present in database (using if else) and if it is present then the label(Enter updated CIE 2 marks) and entry widget(e2) is suppossed to show in the tkinter form. Everything is working perfectly , the if condition is also working and is showing if the USN exists only , the label and the entry widget , but the only problem is the entry widget is uneditable. Please help! 
Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import MySQLdb
from tkinter import *

import os
from subprocess import call

import sys

mydb=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="root",database="mysql")
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

root=Tk()
root.title("Fill the form to Update , delete and display")
f = Frame(root,height=550,width=500)
f.propagate(0)
f.pack()



e1=IntVar()
e2=IntVar()


def insert():
    call(["python","studentdb.py"])


def update():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student WHERE usn=%s",([e1.get()]))
    myresult=mycursor.fetchall()
    if(myresult==()):
    ##print('Unrecognised USN')
    l2=Label(text='Unrecognised USN')
    l2.place(x=50,y=150)
else:

    l2=Label(text='Enter Updated CIE2 Marks:')
    e2=Entry(f,width=25,fg='white',bg='blue')
    l2.place(x=50,y=150)
    e2.place(x=100,y=150)









menubar=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)
filemenu=Menu(root,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Insert Record",command=insert)
filemenu.add_command(label="Display all records",command=display)


filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Select Database Operation",menu=filemenu)




l1=Label(text='Enter Student USN:')
e1=Entry(f,width=25,fg='white',bg='blue')


l1.place(x=50,y=100)
e1.place(x=200,y=100)



b=Button(f,text='Update Record',command=update)
b.place(x=50,y=250)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have indentation error, starting at line `##print ...`. On every click `Button(..., 'Update Record', ...` you create a new `Label` and `Entry` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `state` option in Entry. It has 3 options `disabled`, `normal` and `readonly`.

Use `disabled` when you want to restrict access to the Entry, `normal` to allow the user to do the same. `readonly` can be used when you want to insert information via code and not allow the user to edit the contents. (In your case `readonly` is not neccessarily needed, though)

Comment: Thank you Sir! It was a little typo in my code and i had to reposition the entry widget